# CSS styles are not applied in gtk4 using c language

Tags: css, c, gtk4

I am trying to add a custom coloring to the buttons and elements in a gtk4 GUI written in c language, from the [docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.set_font_options.html?q=gtk_widget_class) I found the functions to load and set the css class name for the different widget that i am using but for some reason the styles are not applied and I get a window with a white background containing only a button with a white color

```
static void activate(GtkApplication * app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget * window;
    GtkWidget * box;
    GtkWidget * btn;
    GtkWidget * txt;
    GtkEntryBuffer * text;
    GtkCssProvider * provider;


    // create window
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "CSS example");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 800);


    // load css file 
    provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file (provider, g_file_new_for_path ("styles.css"));
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display (gtk_widget_get_display (window),
                                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);



    // create the box and set the height and width 
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);

    // add box to main window
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window),box);
    
    // create text 
    text = gtk_entry_buffer_new("hello world", strlen("hello world"));

    // create text widget 
    txt = gtk_text_new();
    gtk_text_set_buffer(GTK_TEXT(txt), text);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), txt);

    // use css from file 
    gtk_widget_class_set_css_name(GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS (txt), "txt");

    // adding button 
    btn = gtk_button_new_with_label("clickme");
    g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_hello), NULL);
    gtk_widget_class_set_css_name(GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS (btn), ".btn");
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), btn);


    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}
```

here is `styles.css`

```
.txt 
{
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
}


.btn
{
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Why isn't this code applying the css to the GUI application

Comment: May be there is some problem with accessing the CSS file, and not with applying styles to a window. Have you considered testing the result of `gtk_css_provider_load_from_file()`...?

Comment: @CiaPan how would i do such thing `gtk_css_provider_load_from_file` does not return anything

Comment: Woops... GTK3 used to provide both a return value of the `gboolean` type and an option to prepare a `struct GError` container to receive an error description ([doc 3 link](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.CssProvider.load_from_file.html)), but GTK4 apparently assumes nothing can go wrong ([doc 4 link](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.CssProvider.load_from_file.html)).

Comment: Possibly you'll have to follow a hint from [GTK4 CssProvider doc](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.CssProvider.html): _'To track errors while loading CSS, connect to the [`GtkCssProvider::parsing-error`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/signal.CssProvider.parsing-error.html) signal.'_

Comment: As no better suggestion appears, I copied my comment above to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you'll have to follow a hint from [GTK4 CssProvider doc](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.CssProvider.html): *'To track errors while loading CSS, connect to the [`GtkCssProvider::parsing-error`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/signal.CssProvider.parsing-error.html) signal.'*

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the period in setting the name or referring to it, as that interferes with css functionality.
So `gtk_widget_class_set_css_name(GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS (btn), ".btn");` should become

```
gtk_widget_class_set_css_name(GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS (btn), "btn");
```

and in your CSS file .btn should be just

```
btn {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Keep in mind `gtk_widget_set_name()` may be what you are looking for, as it does not compmletely remove the native css styling of the GtkWidget. The name you set here can be referred to in the CSS file with a hashtag.